# geometry with quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, circles

If the diagonals of a convex quadrilateral are divided into parts $w, x$
and $y, z$ by their point of intersection, then it is a tangential quadrilateral if and only if the angle $\theta$ between the diagonals satisfies
$$\cos \theta=\dfrac{(w-x)(y-z)(2(wx+yz)-\sqrt{(w-x)^2(y-z)^2+4(wx-yz)^2})}{(w+x)^2(y+z)^2-16wxyz}$$

So please help me how to prove the statement above!

Here is what I know:

- A convex quadrilateral is tangential if and only if its consecutive sides $a, b, c, d$ satisfies Pitot’s theorem, which is $a+c=b+d$.
- $a^2=w^2+y^2-2wy\cos \theta$
- $b^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos \theta$
- $c^2=x^2+z^2-2xz\cos \theta$
- $d^2=w^2+z^2-2wz\cos \theta$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to prove it?

Comment: It's not clear from your post at all. The quote "Here is what I know or proved" doesn't clarify which of the following you proved and which you did not. In any case, please edit the post so it qualifies as a proper question according to Math.SE guidelines

Comment: Sorry...OK now?

Comment: Please also edit the title. In addition, it would be very nice to know how you found these properties, which of them are already known (as far as you can tell) and which of them you are sure haven't been known before. I retracted my close vote for now